# How to disable windows login (so that WAMP can auto start)

Tags: authentication, windows, wamp

I have Wamp 3.2.6 installed on a Windows 10 machine. I use it to serve photos and other files, and some apps, to my local community. Its not mission critical, so I don't monitor the machine constantly.

Unfortunately, whenever windows auto updates, and reboots -- the server goes down. And it might be hours or longer before I realize it.

So I want to  autostart WAMP, which seems to mean I have to disable windows login.

However, I am having trouble suppressing windows login. I tried a few on line resources, but had issues.

What to do?

See my answer for a process that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for auto starting Wamp.

One useful guide was (in addition to the   typically less useful microsoft answers)
https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_disable_the_windows_10_login_screen.html.
But it alone wasn't enough.
So the following outlines what steps I used. Since this machine is ONLY used as a http server, and is located where only I can physically access it, I am willing to sacrifice some security.

a) Enable local logon. I was prompted to consider using a 'Microsoft account'. Since I don't care about syncing this machine to anything, this is an easy consideration to ignore.

```
 Windows setting 
 Accounts
 Your info
 Select 'signin with a local account'
 You will have to enter a new user account, with a password etc.
 Select next and then signout.
```

I rebooted just to be sure it worked. You might have to type in the new username -- my old one
(assigned when I first got the machine) was the default.

Being forgetful, I recorded my new username and password in safe place.

Reference:   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/switch-your-windows-10-device-to-a-local-account-eb7e78a9-88ee-9bc3-8f06-831b56e339fd

b) Disable auto login (an augmented version of the reference below)

```
 Using WindowsKey + R, run netplwiz
 Select your username
 Uncheck the "Users must enter a username and password"... button
```

I had an issue: there was no such checkbox!

Following instructions (in the reference below), I ran regedit (via the search box) to change my registry

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device
 set "DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion" to 0
```

Then I could go back to netplwiz, and check the "Users must ..." checkbox. The next step was ...

```
 Enter your username and password when you 'apply' this change. 
It will the "user that is automatically signed in".
```

And then ...

```
 WindowsKey + S, enter Sign-in options 
 Set "Require sign-in" to never
```

c) You might want to use ...

```
 WindowsKey + S
 Power & Sleep
 Set Sleep to 'Never'.
 Set Screen to 'Never'  
(this may be overkill, but I prefer physically turning the monitor off!)
```

Reference: https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_disable_the_windows_10_login_screen.html

The next step was to auto-start Wamp.

I tried using

```
 WindowsKey -R 
 shell:startup
 Drag a shortcut of my Wamp icon to the startup folder
```

But that didn't work.

So as noted in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761340/have-wamp-start-automatically-upon-windows-start-up-without-logging-on-or-any-u).

```
 Run services.msc (by entering services.msc in the "type here to search" box)
 Find the "wampapache" (or maybe wampapache64) service.
 Right click, go to properties, set startup type to "automatic"
 Perhaps do the same with "wampmysqld" (or wampmysqld64)
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761340/have-wamp-start-automatically-upon-windows-start-up-without-logging-on-or-any-u

Now rebooting the machine will automatically start Wamp!
There is one small issue  -- the Wamp icon isn't in the "hidden icons".
Perhaps there is a way to achieve this, but if/when I need to check Wamp status (say, run phpmyadmin) it is simple enough to start wamp the normal way (clicking on its desktop icon) to bring up the green wamp icon (for viewing status, etc).
It doesn't seem to start a new instance of wamp, but maybe there is a better way?